# How to list my app with a different name in other apps chooser intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have an activity that receives ACTION_SEND intent, so my app shows up when user clicks "Share" button in another app. By default, my app shows up with the app name as the title in the intent list, how can I change the title to something else?

For example, Pinterest's app name is "Pinterest", but it shows up as "Add a pin" in other app's share list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:label` on [the `<intent-filter>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) should cover this. Set that to be whatever you want to see on the chooser.